# Multivariate ANOVA in python

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, manova

I'm running a multivariate 2-way analysis and would like to know how to proceed. Basically, I have two effects `group` and `time` and many features.

```
sample  f1  f2  f3  f4  group   time
S1      31  22  25  28  A       t1
S2      31  22  25  28  A       t1
S3      31  22  25  28  B       t2
S4      30  22  25  28  B       t2
S5      30  22  25  28  B       t2
...
```

Basically, I want to test **whether `f1`, `f2`, etc  differ between groups, and between time**. This sounds to me like a multivariate 2-way ANOVA. I may add more independent variables later, so it may become a 3- or 4-way MANOVA.

It is unclear to me how this can be done with `statsmodels` or other python packages, so I'm reaching out hoping for some help.

I see that I could do it like this, but I'm not sure if I got it correctly:

```
from statsmodels.multivariate.manova import MANOVA
maov=MANOVA.from_formula('group + time ~ f1 + f2 + f3 + f4', data=widedf)
print(maov.mv_test())

                           Multivariate linear model
================================================================================
                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Intercept             Value       Num DF  Den DF      F Value      Pr > F
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Wilks' lambda          0.0000 16.0000 458.0000 39329981862.6904 0.0000
         Pillai's trace          1.0000 16.0000 458.0000 39329981862.6904 0.0000
 Hotelling-Lawley trace 1373973165.5088 16.0000 458.0000 39329981862.6904 0.0000
    Roy's greatest root 1373973165.5088 16.0000 458.0000 39329981862.6904 0.0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               group             Value      Num DF     Den DF     F Value    Pr > F
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Wilks' lambda    0.9163    16.0000    458.0000     2.6164    0.0006
               Pillai's trace    0.0837    16.0000    458.0000     2.6164    0.0006
       Hotelling-Lawley trace    0.0914    16.0000    458.0000     2.6164    0.0006
          Roy's greatest root    0.0914    16.0000    458.0000     2.6164    0.0006
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                time             Value      Num DF     Den DF     F Value    Pr > F
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Wilks' lambda    0.9102    16.0000    458.0000     2.8254    0.0002
               Pillai's trace    0.0898    16.0000    458.0000     2.8254    0.0002
       Hotelling-Lawley trace    0.0987    16.0000    458.0000     2.8254    0.0002
          Roy's greatest root    0.0987    16.0000    458.0000     2.8254    0.0002
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                       ...
```

From my understanding, this tells me that the means of `group` and `time` are statistically different based on all features, and now I need to use some post-hoc test to check what is different.

From this [example](https://www.marsja.se/python-manova-made-easy-using-statsmodels/) and [the corresponding jupyter notebook](https://github.com/marsja/jupyter/blob/master/MANOVA_Test_in_Python_Statsmodels_Example.ipynb), it seems that the variables are reversed, which caused some confusion to me. In the post, it seems that it is being tested whether `species` is differing as a function of the features (`Sepal_Length`, `Sepal_Width`, etc.)

My questions are:

- Is my interpretation of problem formulated correctly code-wise?
- It seems to me that the test done in the [example](https://www.marsja.se/python-manova-made-easy-using-statsmodels/) is reversed, or did I miss it?
- [Employing OLS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42160020/1379826) could be also an approach, as it sounds like it is similar to MANOVA. Would it be preferable to use this?

Comment: It looks like your example has reversed formula, general formula in R and statsmodels is `"outcome ~ explanatory variabels`. Based on your description, the outcome variables are `"f1 + f2 + f3 + f4"`and "group + time" are the explanatory variables or covariates

Comment: Thanks @Josef, nice catch. I've edited my example

Comment: Did you rerun with changed formula? `maov=MANOVA.from_formula('f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 ~ group + time', data=widedf)`